# Can I make multiple connections at the same time with Stomp?

Tags: javascript, angular, stomp

I'm using ng2-stomp-service in my Angular app.

Does it make sense to establish multiple connections (not multiple subscriptions)?  In the past, I've only seen a single connection being made, and from there we make multiple subscriptions.  But now my colleague is suggesting I make three connections, and I have a different subscription to each one. The rationale (I'm told) is so that if we lose connection to one, we still have a connection for the others.

I'm not even sure how I'd code this.  Presently, I have one connection.  It looks like this:

```
       if (this.stomp.status !== 'CONNECTED') {
            this.stomp.configure(this.socketConfig);
            this.stomp.startConnect().then((frame) => {
              this.stomp.done('init');
            });

            this.stomp.after('init').then(() => {
                this.reestablishSubscriptions();
            });
        }
```

But it seems like if I were to make multiple connections, I would need more instances of stomp itself, like this.stomp, this.stomp2, this.stomp3, each one calling their own connect function?  Or can a single this.stomp establish multiple connections?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not make sense to establish multiple connections.  What you should do is establish a single connection, and if that connection is lost, re-establish it.

If you did have multiple connections, it is likely that if one of them dropped out then all of them would drop out at the same time.  This could be caused by a network issue or the message broker restarting or dropping your connections due to inactivity.  To avoid a connection being dropped due to inactivity, specify a heatbeat (supported by the stomp protocol v1.1 and higher).

You are correct, you would need one stomp object (instance) for each connection.  So for multiple connections you would need multiple stomp objects.